# using fseek() to find position entered by user

Tags: c, fseek

I need to ask the user for an ID Number, and then use the function `fseek()` to find the position of the ID Number entered by the user, and then be able to modify the records. I have something like this:

```
printf("Enter ID Card Number: \n");
scanf("%s", editCust.idNumber);
fseek(custFile, (editCust.idNumber -1)*sizeof(struct customer), SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: am i using the fseek() function right?

Comment: You are if `custFile` is the handle to your open file, and the second argument resolves to the correct file offset, which I don't have the information to confirm. Did you try it?

Comment: I am new to C.. I have tried it, and I am getting the error "invalid operands to binary * (have 'char *' and 'unsigned int')" 

custFile is the open file yes, I was not sure what to put in the second argument

Comment: Well, that's probably information you might have included in the original question. Are you sure you're getting this error on the `fseek()` line?

Comment: This is the first question I asked, I don't know how this exactly works, yeah it's on the fseek() line, so this line should be correct?

Comment: @JonathanWood Look at the `scanf` format.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, I see it. Including the error message and the line where it occurs would have saved a lot of time.

Comment: Once you get everything else sorted out, be sure that `custFile` is opened in binary mode.  Otherwise you may get unexpected results from fseek due to CR/LF conversion issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

First, substitute:

> scanf("%s", editCust.idNumber);

for

> scanf("%d", &editCust.idNumber);

%s is for string values and %d is for decimal values.

A good source of formats can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Comment: My idNumber is a string value

Comment: @user1928374 Then you have to convert it to an integer (using `strtol` or similar) to do arithmetic with it.

Comment: Right, but see, you are substracting 1 from a string value then, as explained by Daniel Fischer.